# Add "Open MSYS terminal here" in the Windows right click context menu?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, msys

In Windows file explorer,if I hold <kbd>shift + right-click</kbd> on a folder (in a folder too) I can choose to `Open command window here`.  I'd really like to add an `Open MSYS terminal window here` to the popup right click context menu. Is there some way to do that?

[image: Windows right click context menu open command windows here]

Comment: It would be great if OP could tell us how he solved the issue of getting the right directory inside MSYS. I have the context menu, but the terminal always starts with the same working directory (the one set in .profile).

Comment: These are the settings I ended up with: https://gist.github.com/magthe/a60293fe395af7245a9e. There is one issue I haven't solved: the started shell is not a login shell, so `/etc/profile` isn't loaded and with it quite a bit of configuration is missing.  If I add a `-l` to the bash invocation it becomes a login shell, but I always end up in `$HOME`.  I am loathe to make changes to files in `/etc` so any suggestions not requiring that would be most welcome.

Comment: Of course writing the comment above prompted me to look into things a bit and I found a comment in `/etc/profile` that shows how to get a login shell in a specific location.  I've added that as a comment to the github gist I linked to above.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! Just a note to future readers: this solution uses some utilities from Cygwin, so it won't work without some additional fiddling if you use MSYS with MinGW.

Comment: If you use [MSYS2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/) you get those utilities and you won't need to pull in Cygwin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html) and [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) programs to add new features to the right click context menu of File Explorer (Windows Explorer) or you can do it manually by [hacking the registry](http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/).

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171(v=vs.85).aspx) is some more information from Microsoft you won't probably need.

Comment: Doing it manually turned out to be the easiest option.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a script for generating the `.reg` and `.bat` files you will need for the right-click menus (mingw64/32, msys2).      [GitHub: msys2-mingw-shortcut-menus](https://github.com/njzhangyifei/msys2-mingw-shortcut-menus)